# Store an integer based on a string from a combo box selection in C#

Tags: c#, combobox

What I'm trying to do here is to select a string in comboBox1 and comboBox2, have an integer that is entered into to textBox1 multiplied by a specific number based on the selections made in the comboBoxs and then output the results of that multiplication to another read-only textbox.

comboBox1 has:
if comboBox1 = "Alpha" use integer 170
if comboBox1 = "Bravo" use integer 185
if comboBox1 = "Charlie" use integer 195
if comboBox1 = "Delta" use integer  225

& comboBox2 has:
if comboBox2 = "New" add 0 to the integer value determined in comboBox1
comboBox2 = "Old" add 25 to the integer value determined in comboBox1

Multiply a user defined integer entered in textBox1 by the sum value determined above and output that integer into the read-only textBox.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have some good pseudo-code, what is giving you trouble?

Comment: Help with what? Just go ahead and code it...

Comment: Hint: You'll need to [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the strings to the appropriate type (`int` in this case) to do the calculation.

Comment: I'm very new to C#, so I guess my question is how do I associate the string "alpha" with the specific integer 170? Once I've got that down I'm pretty sure I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either use a `Tuple<string, int>` or a class for the items in the list. Maybe something like:

```
class CBItem
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public CBItem(string text, int value)
    {
        Text = text;
        Value = value;
    }

    // This will determine what you see in the combobox
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text ?? base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can add a bunch of `CBItem`s to your combobox instead of just strings:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new CBItem("Alpha", 170));
comboBox1.Items.Add(new CBItem("Bravo", 185));
comboBox1.Items.Add(new CBItem("Charlie", 195));
comboBox1.Items.Add(new CBItem("Delta", 225));

comboBox2.Items.Add(new CBItem("New", 0));
comboBox2.Items.Add(new CBItem("Old", 25));
```

And then in your handler, you can just cast SelectedItem to type CBItem.

```
CBItem cb1Item = (CBItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
CBItem cb2Item = (CBItem)comboBox2.SelectedItem;

int sum = cb1Item.Value + cb2Item.Value;
```

You can figure out how to multiply that sum by the value entered in the textbox from there.